# Dockerization PHP-APACHE MYSQL on centos7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, docker-compose

i have tried creating a docker container on centos7 but
i could access phpmyadmin page but not index.php page

could you see the docker yml and docker file and tell what happened
like im running through kali linux to a centos7 docker its been difficult i have been trying since yesterday

the give code is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.16
        command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci','--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
        ports:
            - "8002:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        volumes:
            - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.9
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: user
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
volumes:
    persistent:
```

and the dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.19-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring
```

i dont know what is the issue like when access localhost:8000 on browser
im getting forbidden access 403 error

i just need to access index.php when i enter localhost:8000 on browser

please help me out, 
thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, have you watched the logs `docker logs stack_www_1`? Is there an index page in www directory?

Comment: no sir, let me check @StéphaneJeandeaux

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Apr 24 12:17:56.121083 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 24 12:17:56.121139 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND

Comment: Have you called http://localhost:8001?

Comment: @StéphaneJeandeaux i am confused from where i should call this sir?

Comment: Have you entered localhost:8001 on your browser?

Comment: from your web browser.